# Validation of RequestParam using custom @ValidCode annotation doesn't work

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, hibernate-validator, spring-validator

Validation of RequestParam using custom validation annotation @ValidCode doesn't work. But If use @Pattern instead it starts working. What am I doing wrong, please?

The controller:

```
@Validated
@RestController
public class MyEndpoint {
    @RequestMapping(path = "/test", method = GET)
    public MyResponse findItems(@ValidCode @RequestParam("code") String code) {
        return new MyResponse("A001");
    }
}
```

My validation annotation:

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({FIELD, PARAMETER})
@Pattern(regexp = "^[A-Z0-9]{4}?$")
public @interface ValidCode {
    String message() default "{ValidCode.message}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Web MVC config:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public Validator validator() {
        return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
        MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor = new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
        methodValidationPostProcessor.setValidator(validator());
        return methodValidationPostProcessor;
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath></relativePath>
    </parent>

    ...

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        ...
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**BUT** if I change controller method following way validation starts working:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/test", method = GET)
public MyResponse findItems(@Pattern(regexp="^[A-Z0-9]{2}?$") @RequestParam("code") String code) {
    return new MyResponse("A001");
}
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `@ValidCode` is not a constraint annotation.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I found out the problem is it's not Hibernate builtin constraint. Builtin constraint works. And my custom annotation ValidCode works on RequestBody. Please notice it is annotated with Pattern.

Comment: It's not annotated with `@Constraint`, which is mandatory for bean validation constraints. Even for composite ones.

Comment: That's correct, it started work as soon as I added @Constraint on the ValidCode annotation.